# Removing nil not going to the last element in the list

Tags: common-lisp

So I have an assignment where I have to remove nils from a list without using the remove function in common lisp. I got it working for the most part except its not printing out the last element in 1 of the lists.

What I have:

```
(defun removeNILMost (L)
    (cond ((NULL L) NIL)
          ((listp (car L)) (OR (removeNILMost(car L)) (removeNILMost(cdr L))))
          ((not (eq nil (car L))) (cons (car L) (removeNILMost(cdr L))))
          (T (removeNILMost(cdr L)))
    )
)
```

The Output:

```
;;; #2 removeNILMost

(removeNILMost '(NIL X NIL NIL Y  NIL Z))
(X Y Z)

(removeNILMost '(X NIL (Y NIL Z) NIL))
(X Y Z)

(removeNILMost '(NIL (NIL) (X NIL Y) (NIL NIL) Z))
(X Y)

(removeNILMost '(NIL ( (((((NIL) NIL)))))))
NIL
```

The problem one is the 2nd to last output where its just supposed to by (x Y Z).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First, lets clean up the formatting a bit to make things easier to read. Note that leaving hanging parentheses on their own lines is very un-idiomatic in lisps; this isn't a curly-braces language, after all:

```
(defun removeNILMost (L)
  (cond ((NULL L) NIL)
        ((listp (car L))
         (OR (removeNILMost (car L))
             (removeNILMost (cdr L))))
        ((not (eq nil (car L)))
         (cons (car L)
               (removeNILMost (cdr L))))
        (T
         (removeNILMost (cdr L)))))
```

Now, why is `or` being used to combine the results of two recursive calls to `removeNILMost`? Because `or` is short-circuiting, only the first result is returned when *both* are non-empty lists in the pair of calls:

```
(OR (removeNILMost (car L))
    (removeNILMost (cdr L))))
```

This is not the desired outcome, and is the reason that the final `z` is missing with `(removeNILMost '(nil (nil) (x nil y) (nil nil) z))`.

Now, since `removeNILMost` returns a list, `append` is the appropriate function for combining these results to give OP result of `(removeNILMost '(X NIL (Y NIL Z) NIL))` --> `(X Y Z)`. Here the goal must be to both flatten the input list and to remove all `nil`s from it. This change would "fix" OP posted code:

```
(append (removeNILMost (car L))
        (removeNILMost (cdr L))))
```

If the goal is only to remove `nil`s from the input, then the tree structure of the input list should be preserved. The examples *do not* show this, but I suspect that the correct implementation would give:

```
CL-USER> (removeNILMost '(X NIL (Y NIL Z) NIL))
(X (Y Z))
```

To preserve the structure of the list, a conditional can check whether the first result is `nil` or not before consing to the second result:

```
(defun removeNILMost (L)
  (cond ((NULL L) NIL)
        ((listp (car L))
         (let ((left (removeNILMost (car L)))
               (right (removeNILMost (cdr L))))
           (if left
               (cons left right)
               right)))
        ((not (eq nil (car L)))
         (cons (car L)
               (removeNILMost (cdr L))))
        (T
         (removeNILMost (cdr L)))))
```

The following code cleans up the above a bit; note that `kebab-case` is preferred to variations on `camelCase` in lisps. The tests have been reorganized a bit to make the logic more clear.

```
(defun remove-all-nils (L)
  (cond ((null L) '())  ; empty list input remains empty
        ((null (car L))  ; if the first element is NIL, just move on
         (remove-all-nils (cdr L)))
        ((listp (car L))  ; if the first element is a list...
         (let ((left (remove-all-nils (car L)))
               (right (remove-all-nils (cdr L))))
           (if left       ; conditionally CONS the results together
               (cons left right)
               right)))
        (t                ; otherwise the first element is not a list
         (cons (car L)    ; so CONS it to the result of processing the remainder
               (remove-all-nils (cdr L))))))
```

Here are some sample interactions:

```
CL-USER> (remove-all-nils '(nil x nil nil y nil z))
(X Y Z)
CL-USER> (remove-all-nils '(x nil (y nil z) nil))
(X (Y Z))
CL-USER> (remove-all-nils '(nil (nil) (x nil y) (nil nil) z))
((X Y) Z)
CL-USER> (remove-all-nils '(nil a (b (c nil (nil) d) e (nil f g (h nil i (nil j (nil nil) k) l nil m) n ) o p q) r nil))
(A (B (C D) E (F G (H I (J K) L M) N) O P Q) R)
CL-USER> (remove-all-nils '(nil ((nil (nil)) (nil (nil (nil (nil nil)) nil))) nil))
NIL
```